# Pyomo constraint > 100000 OR 0

Tags: constraints, pyomo, indicator

All,

I am working on some code where there is a requirement to buy/sell a minimum of 100,000 packets. If not possible then this should be zeroed.

I have tried a number of things for things for this including:

```py
def objective_rule(model):
      return sum(model.Prices[ProductCount]*model.Amount[ProductCount]*(model.Amount[ProductCount]>100000) for ProductCount in model.Products)
```

But this is slower than expected.
I would like to put an explicit constraint in place. Something akin to:

```py
def minTradesize_Constraint(model):
    return ((model.Amount[ProductCount]>=100000)| \
                   (model.Amount[ProductCount]==0.00) for ProductCount in model.Products)
```

I have looked at indicator functions but the Pyomo continuous approximations don't help.
Any help/guidance appreciated.

Comment: Hi Marxai! Since this is a question about your model formulation, you may have better luck asking it on https://or.stackexchange.com/ rather than this programming-specific equivalent. For example, see this post which should answer your question :)
https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/76/in-an-integer-program-how-can-i-activate-a-constraint-only-if-a-decision-vari

Answer (score 2):

Basically, what you are trying to achieve is make the `model.Amount[ProductCount]` terms take discontinuous values (zero or larger or equal to 100,000). To achieve that, first, you will basically need to define a binary variable: `model.y = pyomo.Var(model.Products, within=pyomo.Binary)`.

Then you will need to add the following constraints:

```
def minTradesize_Constraint1(model):
    return (model.Amount[ProductCount] >= 100000 * y[ProductCount] for ProductCount in model.Products)

def minTradesize_Constraint2(model):
    return (model.Amount[ProductCount] <= M * y[ProductCount] for ProductCount in model.Products)
```

where M is a sufficiently large number (can be a realistic upper bound for your `model.Amount[ProductCount]` variable).

As a result of this formulation, if `y[ProductCount]` is zero, then the `model.Amount[ProductCount]` term will also be zero. If the model wants now to make `model.Amount[ProductCount]` variable take positive values, it will have to set the binary `y[ProductCount]` to 1, hence, forcing `model.Amount[ProductCount]` to become larger or equal to 100,000.

Note: I have formulated the constraints in the same style that you did in your answer. However, if I understand your model correctly, I would say that the first constraint, for instance, should be:

```
def minTradesize_Constraint1(model, ProductCount):
    return (model.Amount[ProductCount] >= 100000 * y[ProductCount]
```

and the `for ProductCount in model.Products` part should be added when you create the Pyomo constraint.

Answer (score 0):

to simplify the solution even further. I added a variable called route_selected

```
 model.route_selected = pe.Var(<a set, for me its routes == r>, domain=pe.Binary, initialize=0, within=pe.Binary)

 model.route_selected = pe.Var(model.R, domain=pe.Binary, initialize=0, within=pe.Binary)
```

thats my dependent variable looks

```
# Variable to solve, this is the variable that will be changed by solver to find a solution
# for each route, port, cust, year combination what should be supplied amount
model.x_rpcy = pe.Var(self.model.R, self.model.P, self.model.C, self.model.Y, domain=pe.NonNegativeIntegers, initialize=0)
```

and then added this constraint

```
for y in self.model.Y:
    for r in self.model.R:
            lhs = sum(self.model.x_rpcy[r, p, c, y] for p in self.model.P for c in self.model.C)
                vessel_size = 1000
                self.model.const_route.add(lhs == vessel_size * self.model.route_selected[r])
                
    model.const_route.add(lhs == vessel_size * model.route_selected[r])
```